# Programatically hiding images in Telerik RadGrid image columns

Tags: image, telerik, hide, radgrid

Greetings,

I've got a RadGrid populated with data from a DB. I've also got an image column which is to display an icon based on whether or not a specific boolean property (called IsDirty) of the object populating the row is true or false. If it's true, show the icon in the image column; if not, show nothing. The icon is the same for every row.

What I'm wondering is if and how this can be done. The best solution I've come up with so far is a hack that would change the image source path based on the value of IsDirty, but this isn't really acceptable, since my app is skinnable and showing a blank image would ruin the look.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I know a help topic that may get you started - it is located here:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdconditionalimagedisplayingridcolumn.html

Dick